# Two footnotes shown together with hyperref support

Tags: footnotes

I want to place two distinct footnotes² in the text³, which have the same content, work both with hyperref and are explained together:

I found some solutions which do that for me by giving the same² footnote² twice. However I want to have two distinct footnotes. Does anyone know how to do that?

Cheers,
Mil

EDIT:
The bigger purpose of my question is to *automatically have all footnotes* (on one output page), *which have the same content, grouped together*.

---

²,³: content of both footnotes

Comment: Any ideas? I have researched everything to be found about footnotes, but I am left clueless. I would appreciate any ideas - even if only suggestions - that you might have. :-)

Comment: What is the larger purpose of this?  But a simple workaround would be to do something like: `Some text.\footnote{\textsuperscript{,2}: content of both footnotes} Some text.\footnotemark`

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea, which works nicely for subsequent footnotes. However it always needs to be done manually. 
The larger purpose of my question is basically that as soon as on one output page there are any two footnotes with the same content, then they are "explained together" in the sense as depicted above.

Comment: In other words: this command needs to know whether any two footnotes appear on the same page **and** have the same content in order to combine the footnote marks?  That is no small feat. (And kind of odd: why not just give the information once at the 'second' footnote?)  More tricky: can other footnotes intervene?  Still, my suggestion was proof-of-concept for a simple workaround, which could be made fancier.  E.g.: `\newcommand\xtrafn[1]{\footnote{\textsuperscript{,\stepcounter{footnote}\arabic{footnote}}: #1}}` and `\newcommand\xtrafnmark{\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\footnotemark}`.

Comment: Yes, for two footnotes it might be just a small, unnecessary tweak. However if I have five or more footnotes on the same page with the same content (e.g., I want to add that except this effect, no other effects in this analysis were significant) it might look weird the four or more footnotes just say "see footnote x". So I was looking for a general solution to do just that - hoping that it might already exist. :-)

Comment: Well, I would edit the question to make clear(er) what your real needs and hopes are.  Now it sounds like you might (want to) have: footnotes 1,2,5,8 that all need to somehow be grouped together while 3, 4, 6, and 7 appear on their own. How complicated is this layout likely to get?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I wanted to keep the initial question as simple as possible - but now it might have become confusing. Indeed the idea is to group all footnotes on one page which have the same content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, this is the best idea I can come up with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\textheight=100pt%
\begin{document}
Some text.\footnote{}
Some text.\footnote{footnote.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However for a full solution one would have to manually define when para is switched off and on as well as changing the spacing between the footnotes. If someone has an idea about how to do that, don't hesitate to share. :)